# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Bz\webapp\public\uploads\2031_ide.png'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mern, multer

i was trying add images to the mongodb using multer npm, but its showing this error, Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\bz\webapp\public\uploads\2031_ide.png

I don't know why this error came, i am just referring a youtube video

ProductRoute.js

```
import express from "express";
import multer from "multer";
import {
  createProductController, deleteproduct, getproducts, updateproducts
} from "../controllers/productController.js";
import { isAdmin, requireSignup } from "../middlewares/authMiddleware.js";

const router = express.Router();

const FILE_TYPE_MAP = {
  'image/png': 'png',
  'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',
  'image/jpg': 'jpg'
}


export const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {

      const isValid = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
      let uploadError = new Error('invalid image type');

      if (isValid) {
          uploadError = null
      }

      cb(uploadError, 'public/uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const filename = file.originalname.replace(" ", "_")
      const extension = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
      cb(null, `${filename}`)
  },
  
})

export const uploadOptions = multer({ storage: storage })

//routes
router.post(
  "/create-product",uploadOptions.single('image'),createProductController,
  requireSignup,
  isAdmin,
  
);
```

Productcreate.js

```
export const createProductController = async (req, res) => {
    const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
    if (!category) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Category')
    const file = req.file;
    if (!file) return res.status(400).send('No image in the request')
    const fileName = file.filename
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;
    let product = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        image: `${basePath}${fileName}`,
        mrp: req.body.price,
        category: req.body.category,
        InStock: req.body.InStock,
        rating: req.body.rating,
        numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
        isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured,
    })

    product = await product.save();

    if (!product)
        return res.status(500).send('The product cannot be created')

    res.send(product);
}
```

please suggest change in the code